# How to call a Method of Model from Controller in Zend Framework 3

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-framework3

I apologize for not framing the question title correctly.
I am working on skeleton Application of zf3 to implement acl.I couldn't figure how to retrieve the row of corresponding email address.I have two controllers AlbumController.php and LoginController.php
**AlbumController.php**

```
private $table;
public function __construct(AlbumTable $table)
{
    $this->table = $table;
}
public function deleteAction()
{
    $user_session=new Container('user');
    if(isset($user_session->email))
    {
      $row=$this->loginTable->getRow($user_session->email);//*Here is the problem*
        if($row['role']=='admin')
        {
            $acl=new Acl();
            if($acl->isAllowed('admin','AlbumController','delete'))
            {
                 $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
                if (!$id) {
                    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album');
                }
            $request = $this->getRequest();
            if ($request->isPost()) {
                $del = $request->getPost('del', 'No');

                if ($del == 'Yes') {
                    $id = (int) $request->getPost('id');
                    $this->table->deleteAlbum($id);
                }
                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album');
            }
            return [
                'id'    => $id,
                'album' => $this->table->getAlbum($id),
            ];
    }
        }
     return $this->redirect()->toRoute('login');
     }
   }
```

**LoginController.php**

```
public $user_session;
public $loginTable;
public function __construct(LoginTable $loginTable)
{
 $this->loginTable = $loginTable;
}
```

I am calling getRow() method of LoginTable.php present in Model
LoginTable.php. But it is throwing an error Call to a member function getRow() on a non-object

**LoginTable.php**

```
class LoginTable
{
protected $tableGateway;
public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
 {
     $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
 }
public function getRow($mail)
{
     $email  =  $mail;
     $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array('email' => $email));
     $row = $rowset->current();
     if (!$row) {
         throw new \Exception("Could not find row $email");
     }
     return $row;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `$this->loginTable->getRow()` in your *AlbumController* class, but you didn't define `loginTable` in this controller. You did it in your *LoginController* class, but this is not the same objects.

Inject a *LoginTable* instance in your *AlbumController*:

**`AlbumController.php`**

```
....

private $albumTable;
private $loginTable;

public function __construct(AlbumTable $albumTable, LoginTable $loginTable)
{
    $this->albumTable= $albumTable;
    $this->loginTable= $loginTable;
}

....
```

**`AlbumControllerFactory.php`** (adapt to your code):

```
class AlbumControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        return new AlbumController(
            $container->get(AlbumTable::class),
            $container->get(LoginTable::class)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: @AI Fonce Thanx for the info.I got it using session variable

Comment: @AI Fonce could you tell me where can i create this factory and how can i call this factory?

Comment: @AzharAhmad Your answer is in the official documentation: read it https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/in-depth-guide/models-and-servicemanager/#writing-a-factory-class

Comment: @AI Fonce actually i am calling this factory into the module.config.php of the Album module. where i am injecting the AlbumTable class instance into the AlbumController but i am getting the error 'Unable to locate services Album\Model\AlbumTable. Which i am creating in this factory. Could you solve my problem. Thanx .